# Как работает цикл: "while <переменная>:"?

Tags: python, циклы

Не могу понять как здесь работает цикл.

Особенно не могу понять что значит: `while a:`. Объясните, что это значит?

```
a = int(input())
b = 0
while a:
  b += a
  a = int(input())
print (b)
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код, дайте индексируемый заголовок, укажите метку языка

Comment: я вот не учу и не знаю пайтон. но догадываюсь, что после while должно идти логическое условие, а int значени приводится к true если оно отлично от нуля.

Comment: я не понимаю почему в условии просто указана переменная "a"

Comment: потому что условия `a > 0` и просто `a` собственно эквиваленты, по указанной выше причине

Comment: а почему там именно просто "а"? я попробовал заменить  "а" на "а>0" и код уже перестал работать так как надо

Comment: Условия `a > 0` и `a` не эквивалентны. Для чисел `a` и `a != 0` эквивалентны.

Comment: я попробовал поменять"a" на "a!=0" и все вновь заработало, спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: написано ж было вверху, что отлично от нуля.

Comment: `while bool(a):` понятнее?

Comment: Кто эти шестеро, которые плюсанули вопрос? Зачем? Почему?

Answer (score 5):

Цикл состоит из оператора while, следующего за ним логического выражения и тела. Тело цикла повторяется до тех пор, пока логическое выражение истинно. В данном случае выражение состоит из одной переменной, значение которой в данном контексте интерпретируется как логическое. Целые числа ложны только тогда, когда равны нулю. Соответственно, тело цикла повторяется до тех пор, пока в переменной `a` в результате ввода оказывается что-либо отличное от нуля.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1182350/revisions